# "Checking password..." on login screen never gives up when I type incorrect password

Tags: 16.04, login, password

If I fat-finger the password when I log into Ubuntu it **never** finishes checking the password.  I can (have!) left the desktop for a day and it still says 'checking password'.  The only recourse is to reboot the machine and (hopefully) enter the correct password.

Where should I start to resolve this?

Comment: Something messed up in your PAM configuration maybe? perhaps `journalctl | grep -i pam | grep -v CRON` will shed some light?

Comment: I'm seeing these two entries repeated:   -desktop lightdm[1168]: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_kwallet.so): /lib/security/pam_kwallet.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory  desktop lightdm[1168]: PAM adding faulty module: pam_kwallet.so

Comment: Based on the error, you seem to be missing `pam_kwallet.so` which on my system belongs to the package  `libpam-kwallet4`. Can you try to reinstall `libpam-kwallet4` and `libpam-kwallet5` ?

Comment: Thanks, arielf.  I will try that in the next couple of days.  I don't even have a /security folder.  FYI - this was an out-of-the-box Ubuntu install.  When the switch to Gnome was announced I installed the Gnome desktop to try out it and have been using it ever since.  Is that a possible cause of this issue?